# d3 tooltip debounce required or not

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have a mousemove function that looks something like this on my d3 chart. `props.metrics` is a list of metrics (not exceeding 10), each containing an array of the metric values.

```js
function mousemove(e: MouseEvent) {
        const x0 = x.invert(d3.pointer(e, svg.node())[0]);
        const i = bisect(dates, x0, 1);
        if (dates[i]) {
            props.setLiveMoves({
                ticker: tickerSymbol,
                metricId: 'price',
                value: props.data.dataY[i],
            });
            props.setLiveMoves({
                ticker: tickerSymbol,
                metricId: 'date',
                value: props.data.dataX[i],
            });
            if (props.metrics) {
                props.metrics.map((entry: TickerMetricStoreFormat) => {
                    props.setLiveMoves({
                        ticker: tickerSymbol,
                        metricId: entry.metricId,
                        value: entry.value[i],
                    });
                });
            }
            focus
                .selectAll(`.${lineClassname}_y`)
                .attr('transform', `translate(${x(dates[i])}, 0)`);
            focus
                .selectAll(`.${lineClassname}_x`)
                .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${y(props.data.dataY[i])})`);
        }
    }
```

this is attached onto a rect that covers the chart area.

```js
 svg.append('rect')
        .attr('class', mousetrackerClassname)
        .style('fill', 'transparent')
        .style('pointer-events', 'all')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .on('mouseover', mouseover)
        .on('mousemove', mousemove)
        .on('mouseout', mouseout);
```

my question is: how expensive is this mousmove function, and whether it is a common design pattern to add debounce to this tooltip hover? If so, how can i implement debounce?

Comment: You don't need to handle both `mouseover` and `mousemove`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing debouncing of events in general is:

- declaring a variable in which you store the id you always get from
  calling setTimeout (needed for clearing the timeout)
- clearing the timeout when the event occurs as well as setting a
  new timeout with a function that will run in a short while (maybe 100ms) and storing the id of the timeout in your variable
- when the even't stops triggering it will not clear the last timeout
  before the function has had time to run...

*Code example:*

```
let mouseMoveTimeout;
window.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  clearTimeout(mouseMoveTimeout);
  mouseMoveTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    /* things to do */
    console.log('Called after 100ms of no mouse moves');
  }, 100);
});
```

And yes, events such as **mousemove**, **scroll** etc do generate a lot of events, so I would recommend debouncing on those, as well as on **keyup**-event in input/search-fields that trigger api calls (around 150-200ms so the user has stopped typing before you send the api-query).